# Номер в таблице

Tags: php, html, css

Как узнать номер элемента в таблице **dl** и назначить ему свой стиль? Элемент задан через **dt**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу с использованием jQuery:

```
$('dt').click(function(){
   var ndx = $(this).index();
   alert('Вы выбрали №'+ndx);
   $('dl').eq(ndx).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

update: Тогда так, если я правильно понял, что Вам нужно.

```
dt:first-child {
   background-color: red;
}
dt:nth-child(2) {
   background-color: green;
}
dt:last-child {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: В этом и вся загвоздка div open всего один и он прыгая заменяет div'ы close, бесполезно использовать псевдоклассы.

Comment: Я никак не могу понять чего вы хотите добиться. Если просто назначит каждому пункту свой стиль, то можно его по id просто указать.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем подходит, вот так выглядит таблица:

http://h1964807.stratoserver.net/files/share/11_1_2012/EfyEBGk3CUat2tIUY4Nmpg.png

Вот так в коде:

http://h1964807.stratoserver.net/files/share/11_1_2012/ScwNVKbX9keJprnBH4PJ3w.png

Хочу сделать отображение open дива (белый) разным, для первой и последней позиции. (кстати open блок всегда активен)

Comment: вообщето, это чистой воды ul, li должен быть.

Comment: shurik +1, но как говорится "хозяин - барин" ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Напишу с использованием jQuery:
>
> $('dt').click(function(){    var ndx =
> $(this).index();    alert('Вы выбрали
> №'+ndx); 
> $('dl').eq(ndx).css('background-color',
> 'red'); })

Чем не подходит этот вариант? Просто добавьте множитель и меняйте

```
 index = $(this).index();
 red = 255 / index;
 green = 255 /index;
 blue = 255 / index;

 $('dl').eq(index).css('background-color','rgb('+red +','+green+','+blue+')');
```